# How to place a button inside its parent container so that it perfectly covers the border of that container

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to recreate this component that consists of a button on the far right corner and a label that shows the name of file.
[image]

In order to get that result, I'm using absolute position for the button, but you can easily tell that the button is inside its parent and not on top of it

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="ctrl">
  <div class="upload">
    <label class="upload__file-name">Select a file</label>
    <button type="button" class="upload__choose">
      Browse
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 62.5%; //1 rem = 10px; 10px/16px = 62.5%
  background-color: #562765;
 
}


body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

.file-input {
  display: none;
}

.ctrl {
  height: 4.8rem;
}

.upload {  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(#F0F0F0, 0.32);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 0 0 23px;
  position: relative;
  &__file-name {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 120%;
    color: rgba(#fff, 0.48);
  }
  &__choose {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 12px 40px;

    background: linear-gradient(
        100.77deg,
        rgba(222, 102, 251, 0.4) 0%,
        rgba(222, 102, 251, 0) 53.8%
      ),
      #7036e9;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 24px -1px rgba(13, 8, 70, 0.4);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    border-radius: 40px;
  }
}
```

Here's a [codepen with the HTML + CSS (Sass)](https://codepen.io/axell9641/pen/mdmYWgv?editors=1100) I used.

Is there any way I can make the button look like as it were placed on top of its container? In other words, how can I align the button's top, right, and bottom borders with its parent container?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `z-index`?

Comment: You need to specify the border-radius for the inner element matching with the parent.

Answer (score 2):

So as you can see in the below snippet, both `container` as well as to the button, the `border-radius` is `40px` and `padding` is `15px`.

So both will work accordingly.

Since the button is `position: absolute`, I have aligned it to the right most of the input. Both elements have same height due to the above mentioned reasons, the button will cover the entire area of input also.

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container input {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.container button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
        100.77deg,
        rgba(222, 102, 251, 0.4) 0%,
        rgba(222, 102, 251, 0) 53.8%
      ),
      #7036e9;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #7036e9;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <input type="text" />
  <button>Explorer</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed to remove the `padding` from the parent container and also the `top` property from the button to make it work. What I like about your solution is that even if I increase the zoom the button does not end up covering the label as it does in my solution. How did you that?

Answer (score 1):

Move the `position: relative` property to the ***`.ctrl`*** elements selector to make the *absolutely positioned* element *relative* to *its* **border-box** and not that of the ***upload*** element which is essentially the placeholder for the *"input"* background. Since it will then be taken out of the regular document flow and absolutely placed to the ***.upload*** elements parent, this will give the button the look that it is on top of the ***.upload*** element.

Provided the upload width inherits its parents width, you could also remove any residual border that may be showing underneath the button using a  calculated width on the upload width property, something like `width: calc(100% - 2px);`

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background-color: #562765;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

.file-input {
  display: none;
}

.ctrl {
  height: 4.8rem;
  position: relative;
}

.upload {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.32);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 0 0 23px;
}
.upload__file-name {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.48);
}
.upload__choose {
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(100.77deg, rgba(222, 102, 251, 0.4) 0%, rgba(222, 102, 251, 0) 53.8%), #7036e9;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 24px -1px rgba(13, 8, 70, 0.4);
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" class="file-input">

<div class="ctrl">
  <div class="upload">
    <label class="upload__file-name">Select a file</label>
    <button type="button" class="upload__choose">
      Browse
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have tried this, you can check
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background-color: #562765;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

.file-input {
  display: none;
}

.ctrl {
  height: 4.8rem;
}

.upload {
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.32);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 0 0 23px;
  position: relative;
}
.upload__file-name {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.48);
}
.upload__choose {
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(100.77deg, rgba(222, 102, 251, 0.4) 0%, rgba(222, 102, 251, 0) 53.8%), #7036e9;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 24px -1px rgba(13, 8, 70, 0.4);
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  border-radius: 40px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" class="file-input">
<div class="ctrl">
  <div class="upload">
    <label class="upload__file-name">Select a file</label>
    <button type="button" class="upload__choose">
      Browse
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```